# How to capture the href attribute of an internal link in jQuery and use the value of # for selecting a div tag Id

Tags: jquery

I have an a navigation which contains links such as:

```
<a href="#div1">DIV 1</a>
<a href="#div2">DIV 2</a>
<a href="#div3">DIV 3</a>
```

Also I have three div tags as follow

```
<div id="div1"> SOME CONTENT </div>
<div id="div2"> SOME CONTENT </div>
<div id="div3"> SOME CONTENT </div>
```

I want that when I click on

```
<a href="#div1">DIV 1</a>
```

then it shows the content of

```
<div id="div1"> SOME CONTENT </div>
```

and hide all other DIV tags and so on..

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    var d = this.hash;       // contains just the hash portion of the clicked URL
    $('div').not(d).hide();  // hide every other div
    $(d).show();             // show this one
    e.preventDefault();      // prevent page reload
});
```

That said, you really ought to have some other class attached to those divs that are supposed to be hidden or shown, to ensure that you can use divs within the rest of your markup.

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/JZ7rj/

Comment: You can pass the `href` value directly to the selector, no need for `substring` ;)

Comment: @Felix good catch!  it didn't occur to me that the character I was removing was the same one I was then adding on ;-)

Comment: What should I say? These things happen to all of us :)

Answer (score 0):

Give your divs same class e.g. "mydivs", then you can do:

```
$("a").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("href");
  $(".mydivs").hide();
  $(id).show();
})
```

Comment: nb: not really correct to hide _everything_ then just show the one you want.  if you were to add animation it would foul things up. Also, `.href` is likely to be a full URL, not just the text that was in the tag.